# Trying to sum from array

Tags: arrays, ruby, sum, integer, addition

```
    a = gets.split(" ").each {|n| n.to_i}
    puts "#{a[0] + a[1]}"
```

Say I input 1 2 into the above code.
The output will be 12.
How to do a simple addition with this code? For the output to be 3

Comment: simply it would be `gets.split.map(&:to_i).reduce(:+)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`each` won't change the array. You should use `map!`

```
a = gets.split(" ").map! {|n| n.to_i}
puts "#{a[0] + a[1]}"
```

Comment: There's no need to use `map!`, `map` will return a new list which will be assigned to `a`. `split(" ")` is already the default behavior, you can leave out the parameter. `{|n| n.to_i}` could be shortened `&:to_i`. In the end, `a = gets.split.map(&:to_i)`

Comment: @ephemient Yes, `map` does work. But I still prefer `map!` because it modifies the array in place, while `map` introduces an intermediate array thus adds burden to GC.

Comment: `map!` really is the wrong method here. It makes your code less readable and with such a small object, it won't make any difference at all, especially when combined with `gets`. The string interpolation is also unneeded.

Comment: @EricDuminil What do you mean by "less readable"? Is `map` less readable? If it is not, how can `map!` be less readable?

Comment: `map!` implies that you want to modify the array in place for some good reason.  But you create this array on the fly just before with `split(" ")` (which could be just `split` BTW). The two don't fit together and send mixed signals to the reader. Please take a lookt at Cary's answer for a clearer, more robust method.

Comment: @EricDuminil "But you create this array on the fly just before with `split(" ")`" that's why I'm using `map!` because we don't need the intermediate array created by `split` anyway, so why not just mutate it? I agree that `reduce` is good, I'd use it in my own program, after a `map!` (mapred, mmh, sounds familiar), but the OP only asked about where was wrong in his program, so I gave a minimal change in the code.

Comment: You're right that it's always a good idea to include a corrected code that is as close as possible to OP's. But then, you'd really need to add a few points to explain how it could be written in a more Rubyish way. Using `map!` is just premature optimization. If you care about memory and nanoseconds, you shouldn't be using Ruby anyway.

Comment: Note that if `gets` returns `s = "1   2"` (with 3 or more spaces between `1` and `2`), `s.split(" ") #=> ["1  2"]`, whereas `s.split #=> ["1", "2"]`, which is what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose `gets` returns

```
s = "21 14     7"
```

Then use [Array#sum](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-sum) (new in Ruby v.2.4.0):

```
puts s.split.sum(&:to_i)
42
```

or use [Enumerable#reduce](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) (aka `inject`, available since the dawn of time)

```
puts s.split.reduce(0) { |t,ss| t+ss.to_i }
42
```

Answer (score 1):

Though accepted answer is correct but only for **array with two elements**(even for array with 1 element it will break). What if array size is variable? Ruby has more generic ways to do it.

You can use either `reduce` or `inject` method
[documentation](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/reduce)

example code:

```
a = gets.split(" ").map! {|n| n.to_i}
puts a.reduce(:+)
```

If I enter `1 2 3 4 5 6 7` then it will output `28`

Like `reduce` you can use

```
a = gets.split(" ").map! {|n| n.to_i}
puts a.inject(:+)
```

Hope it will help someone.

Comment: You should use `map`, not `map!`.

Comment: @EricDuminil Since accepted answer use `map!` I just showed how we can improve that.

Answer (score 0):

one-liner using [Enumberable#map](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/map) and [Enumberable#reduce](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/reduce)

```
gets.split.map(&:to_i).reduce(:+)
```